# Magento 2.2.7 admin panel blank page

Tags: magento2.2.7

After successful installation when i run the admin url it's giving me this. I'm not sure what's happening. So if anyone have any solution for this it will be great help.

[image]

Comment: check logs may be something thair

Comment: i don't know actually what to check in logs. This is the first time i'm installing magento. Can you be more specific?

Comment: which os r u using

Comment: @AdarshShukla windows 10

Comment: find errors.log file in your server

Comment: Sorry there's no such file in the var/log directory

Comment: what are u using wamp or xamp

Comment: @AdarshShukla xampp

Comment: \xampp\apache\logs\error.log, where xampp is your installation folder

Comment: also check consol logs

Comment: [ssl:warn] [pid 10848:tid 500] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
 [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10848:tid 500] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

**Update**

This is Magento bug. Wrong paths to Windows are generated. The fixed fix is

**Magento 2.3.0 - 2.3.3**

```
#/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php:140
```

the string

```
if (0 === strpos($realPath, $directory)) {
    return true;
}
```

> to replace

```
$realDirectory = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($directory);
if ($realDirectory && 0 === strpos($realPath, $realDirectory)) {
   return true;
}
```

**Magento 2.2.7**

```
/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php:113
```

code

```
protected function isPathInDirectories($path, $directories)
{
    if (!is_array($directories)) {
        $directories = (array)$directories;
    }
    foreach ($directories as $directory) {
        if (0 === strpos($this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path), $directory)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

to replace

```
protected function isPathInDirectories($path, $directories)
    {
        $realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
        if (!is_array($directories)) {
            $directories = (array)$directories;
        }
        foreach ($directories as $directory) {
            if (0 === strpos($realPath, $directory)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

If You can't find out the (/vendor/magento/framework/) folder in magento 2.2.7 - 2.3.3 . Then You can check it here:

```
#lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php
```

Comment: `$realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);`
there is no such line

Comment: gave the answer in more detail

Comment: oh my god why, just spent 3 hours on this, magento is shipping code with bugs on a vanilla installation

Comment: Great!! Helped me for 2.2.7

Comment: @Andry Rad, same bug in magento version 2.3.1 also there

Comment: For Magento 2.3.1, the $realPath var exists on line 138

Comment: If you have used composer install for your project then find this file here
```\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\File```

Comment: if it is magento 2.3.2 file path same but line number 138

Comment: Helped me on 2.2.10. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AndreyRad Thanks a lot ..Soln worked with 2.3.4 ..Can you please tell how do you debugged issue is in Validator.php file ?

Comment: Worked in 2020 (not many things do xD)

Comment: Saved my day .Thank you

Answer (score 3):

If you can't find the (/vendor/magento/framework/) folder in magento 2.
Then you can find it here:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php
```