# Magento 2.3.0 not working

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.0

I have install Magento 2.3.0 in php 7.2 xampp windows 7. After installing i have run following command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

When i open admin, i am getting blank screen. no javascript error. On frontend i am getting following error in console

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/magento-230/mage/translate-inline.js"
transla...line.js
Error: Script error for: mage/translate-inline
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror


var e = new Error(msg + '\nhttp://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#' + id);


require.js (line 166, col 17)
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/magento-230/mage/dataPost.js"
dataPost.js
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/magento-230/mage/bootstrap.js"
bootstrap.js
Error: Script error for: mage/dataPost
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror


var e = new Error(msg + '\nhttp://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#' + id);


require.js (line 166, col 17)
Error: Script error for: mage/bootstrap
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror


var e = new Error(msg + '\nhttp://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#' + id);


require.js (line 166, col 17)
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/magento-230/jquery.js"
jquery.js
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/magento-230/jquery/jquery.mobile.custom.js"
jquery....stom.js
Error: Script error for: jquery
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror


var e = new Error(msg + '\nhttp://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#' + id);


require.js (line 166, col 17)
Error: Script error for: jquery/jquery.mobile.custom
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror


var e = new Error(msg + '\nhttp://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#' + id);


require.js (line 166, col 17)
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/magento-230/Magento_Theme/js/responsive.js"
responsive.js
Error: Script error for: Magento_Theme/js/responsive
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror


var e = new Error(msg + '\nhttp://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#' + id);


require.js (line 166, col 17)
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/magento-230/Magento_Theme/js/theme.js"
theme.js
Error: Script error for: Magento_Theme/js/theme
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror


var e = new Error(msg + '\nhttp://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#' + id);
```

Can anyone help me how to fix this error and how magento 2.3.0 work properly in my pc.

Comment: Hope your doing a fresh installation not upgrading the existing one, Just clear files in var/cache/*, var/page_cache/* and generated/code/* and try

Comment: @ArshadM I did that. But still getting same error. I do not know why getting js error. I have try to install many times and getting same error.

Comment: The answer is here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252188/magento-2-2-7-admin-panel-blank-page/252293#252293

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252188/magento-2-2-7-admin-panel-blank-page/252293#252293