# Problems after upgrate magento 2.2.5 to 2.3.0

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento2.3, magento-upgrade

After I upgraded Mageto **2.2.5 to 2.3.0** I've run all the commands in the console (upgrade,deploy,compile,flush), but on frontend it doesn't load the page and in system.log

I'm getting following error

> "main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'theme.active.editor' element cannot
>   be added as child to 'after.body.start', because the latter doesn't
>   exist [] []  main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'logger' element cannot
>   be added as child to 'after.body.start', because the latter doesn't
>   exist [] []"

And in backend i have the error :ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Thank you for any advice

Comment: Drop which php version you are using and which process you followed for upgrade.

Comment: i am using php 7.1 and i've upgraded magento with composer

Comment: Have you followed upgrade doc provided by Magento its bit different process the previous upgrade process.

Comment: i have used this script https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/dev/tools/UpgradeScripts/pre_composer_update_2.3.php and then composer update

Comment: Then should be good is setup:upgrade command run successfully?

Comment: php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:di:compile && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f && php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush all have run successfully

Comment: I think you have Windows, the solution described here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252188/magento-2-2-7-admin-panel-blank-page/252293#252293

Comment: Thank you very much ,that was the problem.thank you again, you saved me :D

Answer (score 0):

The issue in our layout.

First, on the layout, you have a section name `theme.active.editor` .

ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS happen for cookie setting issue at magento.Please check the cookie setting at `core_config_data` table.

**Run below  query:**

```
select * from core_config_data where value like '%cookie%'
```

I guess that on your database, your c**ookie domain is live domain**. So, you have to delete that record. and then Flush All the cache.

Comment: hi Amit ,my project is on local and in my database in core_config_data table i don t have nothing about cookie

Comment: which browser, you have tried?

Comment: @AmitBera I have the same issue. We just moved the instance from nginx server to windows server, since then both frontend and backend dont work. When I open admin I got the same error logged.

Answer (score 0):

First, run the below command:

```
SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` LIKE '%base_url%'
```

Next, if the value is **enabled SSL** then fix to **HTTPS** and if it is **disabled**, please edit to **HTTP**.

Finally, clear cache.

Please let me know if it works!