# Unsupported declare 'strict_types' in Magento 2.3.0

Tags: magento2, composer, magento2.3.0

**Error :** Unsupported `declare strict_types` in 
`../vendor/magento/inventory-composer-installer` while install the extension using composer in Magento 2.3.0.

Comment: Answer in this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252188/magento-2-2-7-admin-panel-blank-page/252293?noredirect=1#comment356360_252293

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, it is due to the version of PHP you are using, and the version of PHP required for Composer.

My CLI was using PHP 5.4, but I had to run it on 7.2.

So instead of running something like:

> composer upgrade

I ran:

> php7.2 /path/to/composer upgrade

Hope this helps. I was confused on this for a little while, as the error doesn't seem related to the PHP version, but seems like more of a bug with the installation.

Comment: I just realised how old this post is (so I assume you have a solution), but I couldn't find much help related to Magento 2.3, so I hope this helps anyone else who comes across it.

Comment: I'm getting this on 2.3.0 on php 7.2.14 :(

Comment: In my case it is the multiphp had reset the php version on the composer folder, which i had to change manually with ln -s  ea-php72 .ea-php-cli.cache

Answer (score 0):

if you still have this problem, just change your PHP version for CLI. If you use WHH you can change it from here:

```
Home »Software »MultiPHP Manager»System PHP Version click edit button and choose PHP 7.2
```