# Magento-CE 2.3.0 installation error on Xampp

Tags: php, error, installation, magento2.3

Error in Installation:

> [php7:error] [pid 10084:tid 1952]
>   [client ::1:53679] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: The
>   path
>   "C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/lavoska/generated/code/Magento/Swatches/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Attribute/Edit/FormFactory.php.10084"
>   cannot be renamed into
>   "C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/lavoska/generated/code/Magento/Swatches/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Attribute/Edit/FormFactory.php"
>   Warning!rename(C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/lavoska/generated/code/Magento/Swatches/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Attribute/Edit/FormFactory.php.10084,C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/lavoska/generated/code/Magento/Swatches/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Attribute/Edit/FormFactory.php):
>   The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another
>   process. (code: 32)\r\nClass
>   Magento\Swatches\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit\FormFactory
>   generation error: The requested class did not generate properly,
>   because the 'generated' directory permission is read-only. If ---
>   after running the 'bin/magento setup:di:compile' CLI command when the
>   'generated' directory permission is set to write --- the requested
>   class did not generate in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lavoska\vendor\magento\framework\Code\Generator.php
>   on line 135, referer: http://localhost:81/magento/lavoska/setup/

Comment: What is the php version you are using?

Comment: I described the problem here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252188/magento-2-2-7-admin-panel-blank-page/252293?noredirect=1#comment356360_252293

Comment: 7.2 php version using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are on windows open the folder and give permissions to generated folder to "uncheck" read only and for linux operating systems use chmod -R 755 generated and you will be able to install the magento 2.3.1

Answer (score 0):

You must set the permission for project and you can do it with you must click right to folder project and unchecked the **"Read-only"** for all files and folders from project.

Comment: I have done that, but that is not unchecking. When process done, that seems again checked. Can you suggest me that why is it happening?

Comment: After unchecked please run all commands which you need and after that re-unchecked.

Comment: How install ? in browser or with **CLI** command ?

Comment: in browser.....