# Magento Admin Panel page is blank - /vendor/magento/framework doesnt exist?

Tags: magento2, admin-panel

I came from reading [Magento 2.2.7 admin panel blank page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252188/magento-2-2-7-admin-panel-blank-page?newreg=1d9a149ffb5c4534b4f550e756ae7758)

However, i have an even more weird issue: The /magento/framework folder doesnt exist. Does anyone have an idea what is going on? I followed the step-by-step guide, created a DB called magento, and then did the installation on the /setup page, then tried to acess admin panel, and its blank.

Found that question, but when i tried to go and fix this, i found out the folder doesnt exist:
[image]

Comment: make sure composer.jason in your directory then run cli command composer install

Answer (score 0):

you can find C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\File in `lib` folder in the home directory of Magento installation and then complete the steps in the link you added [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252188/magento-2-2-7-admin-panel-blank-page)

Answer (score 0):

Full Path For the file (Validator.php) is here
C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php