# Admin/Frontend Blank pages

Tags: magento2.3.3, error-log

I am attempting to install a magento 2.3.3 site on windows and no content is being generated for my page. I have followed many different methods of fixing this. I have changed the Validator realpath variable and more. When i inspect the page, this is the only code that is generated, apart from the head.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head> ... </head>
  <body data-container="body" 
      data-mage-init="{"loaderAjax": {}, "loader": { "icon": "http://localhost/greenbeansau/pub/static/frontend/_view/en_NZ/images/loader-2.gif"}}" 
      class="cms-index-index page-layout-1column">

  </body>
</html>
```

My Admin page also has the same code. As far as i can tell, no errors have been logged in the var/log files, and no php errors are being generated.

Help please. Anything would be appreciated

Comment: please check the log files. or share it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this was caused by Global.php, found in generated/metadata. After deleting it, i was able to access my website.

I have no idea why this works, though.

Answer (score 0):

please refer this [**link**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252188/magento-2-2-7-admin-panel-blank-page) after run Bellow command :

```
php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:upgrade
php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento indexer:reindex
php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento cache:clean
php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento cache:flush
```