# error displaying magento

Tags: magento2

Install magento 2 on my premises and I have these errors and I can't see the system

[image]

Already use the following commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

But this does not solve my problem, the maximum I can see on the screen is this

[image]

How can I solve these errors?

Comment: Hello @Edwin Aquino Please refer this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252188/magento-2-2-7-admin-panel-blank-page hope help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To resolve this issue on the localhost.

> vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php

Find the below code

```
if (0 === strpos($realPath, $directory)) {
    return true;
}
```

And replace it with

```
$realDirectory = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($directory);
if ($realDirectory && 0 === strpos($realPath, $realDirectory)) {
   return true;
}
```

Then flush the cache and your issue will be resolved.