# Magento 2: Errors after installation on xampp

Tags: magento2, error, xampp

I have installed magento 2 on xampp but i have errors on admin and front page

[image]

[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve this issue on the localhost.

> vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php

Find the below code

```
if (0 === strpos($realPath, $directory)) {
    return true;
}
```

And replace it with

```
$realDirectory = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($directory);
if ($realDirectory && 0 === strpos($realPath, $realDirectory)) {
   return true;
}
```

Then flush the cache and your issue will be resolved.

The answer already accepted here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/304239/59677

Comment: and deploy static content too.

Comment: Thnk!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

after installing run the following commands on Magneto root :

```
sudo rm -rf var/di var/generation var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/*
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f 

sudo php bin/magento cache:clean
sudo php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Also, Check the folder permissions.
Hope it helps..

Answer (score 1):

This is Magento 2 bug. And it is fixed.

Please go this file path :-

**/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php:140**

the string

> if (0 === strpos($realPath, $directory)) {
>       return true;
>      }

**to replace**

> $realDirectory = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($directory);
>      if ($realDirectory && 0 === strpos($realPath, $realDirectory)) {
>      return true;
>      }

And your Magento version is 2.3.3 is lower so refer this links :-

[Magento 2.2.7 admin panel blank page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252188/magento-2-2-7-admin-panel-blank-page)

Hope help you.

Thanks.